# Implementing Business Logic in the Context of Entity Framework

Tags: .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

I went through many pages on the web in relations to how business objects and data objects are best put together in the context of Entity Framework.  However, couldn't find a clear and straight forward answer, hence, rendering me confused and I'm still not sure which way is the best way to implement my business logic when using EF (if I insist on having in on a separate layer).

- Does employing Entity Framework mean that your business objects should or best now be integrated/embedded in your "Data Access Layer"/EF application.  Does it mean that there would be no need for a Business Logic "Layer".
- If having a separate "Business Logic Layer" is possible when using EF, how is this accomplished (couldn't find any examples or guide that would cover this).

Answer (score 0):

This is proposed answer, however, I would like to get second opinion as if this is the an acceptable procedure by experienced professionals.

http://aspalliance.com/1943_ASPNET_40_and_the_Entity_Framework_4__Part_4__A_3_Layered_Approach_to_the_Entity_Framework.all